# .htaccess One Url Equals Another with redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I am trying to create a url that is an alias of another url so that when the alias url is typed in it will render the original page without a redirect.

My htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]


</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^/random /c/Just_The_Randoms
RewriteRule ^/adifferent/address /a/somewhereDifferent
```

I built this using laravel and what happens is the alias is created dynamicly and the htaccess file is just rewritten when a new url is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Your "aliases" need to go *before* your existing rewrite, otherwise they are never going to be processed. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Aliases
RewriteRule ^/random /c/Just_The_Randoms
RewriteRule ^/adifferent/address /a/somewhereDifferent

# Route request...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```